# How to update sqlite3 in CentOS 6.6

Tags: sqlite

My CentOS 6.6 has sqlite3 3.6.20 installed, and I tried to update 
by

> yum update sqlite

but it shows 'No Package marked for update'

How can I install/update 3.7.7+ for using shared memory between instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yum can only find newer versions of packages that are available in the yum repositories configured for the machine. If using the stock CentOS repository, SQLite 3.6.20 would be the latest.

You would need to either add a repository with a more recent version, find and download the new version of the software or download the source and compile/install.

From a quick Google search it does appear there are RPMs for CentOS 6 and SQLite 3.7.17.